# Android Remove Duplicate Textview

Tags: java, android, textview

I got sqlite database where I store some infos.

```
ID  NUMBER     posX    posY

1   232342     235     346
2   345.4353   344     123
3   23         124     157
```

I created drag and drop onTouchlistener and it works perfectly and as you see, it stores some infos in database.

**DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:**

```
mCurX = (int) event.getX();
mCurY = (int) event.getY();
```

**DragEvent.ACTION_DROP**

```
final String sql = "INSERT or REPLACE INTO number_dash (numbers, X, Y) VALUES ('"+Dropped.getText()+ "', '"+ mCurX+ "', '"+ mCurY + "')";
db.execSQL(sql);
```

after insert in my database I use **select** statement and it also works perfectly.

```
    Cursor newQuery = db.query("number_dash",null, null, null, null, null, null,null);

    if (newQuery.moveToFirst()) {
      do {
        int ID = Integer.parseInt(newQuery.getString(0));
        String number = newQuery.getString(1);
        float X = Integer.parseInt(newQuery.getString(2)) - 40;
        float Y = Integer.parseInt(newQuery.getString(3)) - 40;

        TX = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
        TX.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());

        TX.setText(number);
        TX.setId(ID);
        TX.setX(X);
        TX.setY(Y);
        TX.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
     } while (newQuery.moveToNext());
   }
```

I thought almost finished my project when I wrote ***update statement***

if I Touch Texview again and dragg in another place (in **Relative layout**) my update statement works well, but the old Texview also stays there.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood well you don't want to have duplicate values on screen right? To avoid that you could have an empty array and before you want to add value (touchlistener) you can add if statement.. something like this :

```
if (!array.contains(value)) {
   array.add(value);
}
```

This if will keep adding textviews as long as they don't have same number..

Comment: Thanks for response, u are absolutely right, but... i don't understand how could old textview also stayed in old position, when i update it in query? how can i remove old one?
thanks...

Comment: you can erase old one like this: yourlayout.removeView(TX);